# Refactoring Code snippet of Cookies and Sessions

Tags: php, cookies, if-statement, refactoring

So I know that this little PHP snippet works, but I want to know if its the best way to do it or if there is a better way to refactor this to make it more efficient. Keep in mind that I am pretty new to PHP in general, so maybe there is an obvious solution that I have simply not learned yet, but I don't know any way to specifically search for this other than to ask you superior minds out there :)

Here is the code snippet, as you see, all I want to do is check that a user is logged in first by checking the session, and secondly by checking a cookie.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    header("Location: http://www.redirect-to-logged-in-site.com");
    exit();
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['Loggedin']) && $_COOKIE['Loggedin'] == true) {
    header("Location: http://www.redirect-to-logged-in-site.com");
    exit();
} //... continue on with something the page for non-current users...

?>
```

As you can see, if the user is logged in they do not need to see the stuff on this page, so i check if they are logged in and if they are, i move them onto the part they need.

Is there a better way to do the same thing? This just seems like it could be easier, i just don't know how to do it. *Help me out fellas*!

Comment: The only *possibly* inefficient thing is the redirect to the logged in site (not doing a redirect would be faster, but is likely a requirement for you), otherwise the logic is sound.

Comment: On second thought, you could decide to use just the session or just a cookie and get rid of one of the checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the duplication of redirecting by combining the two ifs. Also naming the conditionals could make it a little more clear.

```
<?php

$loggedInViaSession = (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true);
$loggedInViaCookie = (isset($_COOKIE['Loggedin']) && $_COOKIE['Loggedin'] == true);

if ($loggedInViaSession || $loggedInViaCookie) {
    header("Location: http://www.redirect-to-logged-in-site.com");
    exit();
}

//... continue on with something the page for non-current users...
```